# What does this SQL trick or injection mean?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

i founded this as some user try to put it in my sql

but using mysql_real_escape_string 
it actully save my website ..

i just want to ask what this code exactly do ..
thanks alot ;)

```
    (select(@) from (select (@:=0x00),(select (@) from (TABLE) where (@) in (@:=concat(@,0x0a,col1,0x3a,col2,0x3a,col3))))a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In an isolated test environment, execute it against a clean database and see what it does. It would also help to see what a `normal` sql statement looks like so it can be compared with the malicious version. As a side note, use prepared statements to prevent sql injection situations.

Always constrain input. Validate all input to your apps for type, length, format, and range.

Comment: okay .. i tried to test it .. but it give me error , si i think mysql_real_escape_string  change it ..  so now i don't know :(  ?

Comment: I do not see any update statement there that would cause your data to change. I would suggest you provide the full sql and post it to a database forum instead ... In the meantime, take precautions as I suggested to protect your site from sql injection